# Using preferredMaxLayoutWidth of NSTextField with auto-layout

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, nstextfield

I'm trying to get an `NSTextField` to auto resize its height based on the text content as the view resizes around it. The closest I've been able to get is be implementing the `layout()` function and setting the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` value to the current size of the frame, but this only works whilst the view is growing.

The text field is constrained to the leading, trailing and top anchors of the main view, with a padding of 50:

[image: Window before dragging the width]

I can drag the right side of the window to increase the width and the `NSTextField` will adjust it's width (auto layout) and height correctly, but then I can't make the window smaller again:

[image: Window after dragging the width]

Any help really appreciated as I've spent way too long trying to solve this problem.

```
let myTextField: NSTextField = NSTextField()

class myView: NSView {

    override func layout() {

        super.layout()
        myTextField.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = myTextField.frame.width
        super.layout()
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: decoder)

        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor

        myTextField.wantsLayer = true
        myTextField.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.yellow.cgColor
        myTextField.bezelStyle = .roundedBezel
        myTextField.isEditable = false
        myTextField.isBordered = false
        myTextField.textColor = NSColor.black
        myTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myTextField.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 50
        self.addSubview(myTextField)
        myTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        myTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
        myTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        myTextField.stringValue = "The width of the inspector is variable and is user controlled. It is not controlled (nor defined by) any constraints. Only the gray views and the NSTextField labels in the screenshots are using auto layout. (And all of this is done in code, not in Interface Builder.) I'll re-visit subclassing and manually doing layout in layout but I was hoping to minic the wrapping behavior seen in Finder's Get Info panel using only constraints."

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't override anything, don't set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` and create the label with `wrappingLabelWithString`. (Or use the Wrapping Label in IB)

Comment: Cannot believe it's that easy! Thanks @Willeke!!!

Comment: Wow, thanks @Willeke, you just saved me so much time, I had `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` set and I was overriding `intrinsicContentSize` and other stuff and getting nowhere. Removing `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` fixed all of it!